# Theta range and double comparison?

Tags: c++, c, double

It seems trivial but I'm not able to solve it. I would like to increase Theta by 15 deg. However, the internal computation by radian. So this is what I did

```
    if ( m_a > PI )
        m_a = m_a - 2*PI;
    if ( m_a <= -PI )
        m_a = m_a + 2*PI;
```

The result for the second if statement should be 0.0. What I got is `5.55112e-016`. It is so small but when I do the following

```
     if ( m_a <= -PI )
            m_a = 0.0;
```

Also, I still get `5.55112e-016`. I'm not sure why? I thought it is because the double comparison, so I did the following

```
   if ( m_a < -PI || isEqual(m_a, -PI) )
        m_a = m_a + 2*PI; // or m_a = 0.0
```

where `isEqual` is ( [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html) for the  link)

```
bool isEqual(double x, double y) 
{
  const double epsilon = 0.000001/* some small number such as 1e-5 */;
  return std::fabs(x - y) <= epsilon * std::fabs(x);
  // see Knuth section 4.2.2 pages 217-218
}
```

I still can't set it to zero. PI is `const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;`

---

Edited:

`m_a` is the angle (Theta) in radian and is increased by 15 deg with an initial value zero as following

```
m_a += (DGR2RAD(15.0));
```

---

Edited:

```
#include <iostream>

const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;  


double DGR2RAD(double angle) 
{ 
    return (angle * PI/180.0); 
}
double RAD2DGR(double angle) 
{ 
    return (angle * 180.0/PI);
}


int main()
{
    double Theta(0.0);

    for (unsigned int i(0); i < 25; ++i)
    {
        Theta += DGR2RAD(15.0);
        std::cout << -PI << " " << Theta << std::endl;
        if ( Theta > PI )
        Theta = Theta - 2*PI;
        else if ( Theta <= -PI )
        {
            std::cout << -PI << " " << Theta << std::endl;
            Theta = Theta + 2*PI;
        }
        std::cout << -PI << " " << Theta << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `m_a` is?  What is the initial value of `m_a`?  Where do `Theta` and the 15 degrees come into play here?  I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Rufflewind, sorry for that. I've updated my post.

Comment: I think you are confused about what radian is/means. It is simply a scale different than degrees for measuring angles. If you want to isolate a certain period like from 0 to 2pi, just do the same you would do for degrees from 0 to 360: use a modulo function.

Comment: I am wondering a bit why you bother to have degrees in the first place since you are dealing with radians? why not just declare a radians constant for 15 degrees and use that when adding to theta? const double fifteenDegrees = PI/12.0;

Comment: @Claptrap, it is more convenient for humans to deal with degrees than radian however in the computation radian is preferable over degrees. Also, if you need to modify the rotation, definitely you will not go and do the calculation again to compute its equivalent radian.

Comment: @Croco and yet you print radians.

Comment: @Claptrap, now I'm tracking the problem. However, for my robot class, it is more convenient to allow the user to determine the rotation angle. In this case I'm sure you will agree that this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @CroCo well I am not saying you should not use radians, just wondered why you bother to do a division/multiplication for each iteration when a constant would have been better. The roundoff error would be slightly less then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still quite confused due to the lack of context for the problem, so here's my best guess.  In particular, I don't understand how adding 15 degrees to the angle `Theta` is at all relevant to the issue here.

Firstly, let's look at this:

```
if ( m_a > PI )
    m_a = m_a - 2*PI;
if ( m_a <= -PI )
    m_a = m_a + 2*PI;
```

I'm guessing the purpose of this code is to make sure that if `m_a` is not in the range from `-PI` to `PI` then it should be brought back into this range (with the caveat that this only works if `m_a` is less than `3 * PI` and no less than `-3 * PI`).

You claim that the `m_a` should be zero after the second `if` block, but are you sure the second `if` block is being executed if the first place?  What *probably* happened instead is that the *first* `if` block ran and set `m_a` to `5.55112e-016`.  Afterwards, the second `if` block was skipped entirely since `5.55112e-016` is not less than or equal to `-PI`.

Since `5.55112e-016` is nowhere near `-PI`, attempting to replace it with a fuzzier check (such as `isEqual`) does nothing to change the result.

In any case, it's probably a good idea to explain what you're trying to do in the first place.  All I can do right now is to explain the symptoms.

Comment: sorry again. I've posted the code in its whole context. If you run the code, you will get the number that I've posted above.

Comment: @CroCo: We don't need more code. We need a better explanation of what you're trying to do and what the problem is with what you're trying to do.